# Python Help Loop Stop

Tags: python

```
try:
    req = r.post(URI, headers=headers, data=Data, stream=True, verify=False)
    try:
        if req.json()["status_code"] == 0:
            impr_id = req.json()["log_pb"]["impr_id"]
            TotalSendedShare += 1
            if DebugMode:
                print(Colorate.Horizontal(Colors.yellow_to_red, f"Shared Amount: {TotalSendedShare})"))
            else:
                print(Colorate.Horizontal(Colors.yellow_to_red, f"Shared Amount: {TotalSendedShare})"))
                Title(f"Thread :{str(active_count() - 1)} / Hit :{TotalSendedShare} / Fail :{TotalFailedReq}")
        else:
            pass
    except:
        TotalFailedReq += -1
        Title(f"Thread :{str(active_count() - 1)} / Hit :{TotalSendedShare} / Fail :{TotalFailedReq}")
except:
    pass
```

I am new to coding and I am just learning to put code together right now. How would I stop this from looping, as it's spamming my command prompt?

This is what it spams btw.

```
Shared Amount: 553)
Shared Amount: 554)
Shared Amount: 209)
Shared Amount: 211)
Shared Amount: 215)
Shared Amount: 557)
Shared Amount: 219)
Shared Amount: 223)
Shared Amount: 227)
Shared Amount: 231)
Shared Amount: 558)
Shared Amount: 237)
Shared Amount: 239)
Shared Amount: 243)
Shared Amount: 247)
Shared Amount: 251)
Shared Amount: 255)
Shared Amount: 259)
Shared Amount: 263)
```

What I want it to send is a single Shared Amount: {amount} then the amount its on not a new message each time

Comment: Is there a loop here? How are you running this?

Comment: Something else is calling this in a loop. That's where you need to stop it.

Comment: have you tried demoting the py file loop functions?

Comment: No how do I do that, full code https://pastebin.com/p2Bq25nU - full code

Comment: Since you are a new contributor, I'm hesitant to close the question out of hand, but you may want to review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You can include the minimal code in your question by editing it, and add links there rather than in the comments.

Comment: Can you explain when you want the loop to stop?

Comment: Take out the `while` loops in your main function.  Also, as general advice, if you're trying to learn coding, I don't recommend starting with a piece of code this long that somebody else wrote; it's too much to try to learn all at once.  Go through a beginner's tutorial.  If you're just trying to use a tool and you don't care about learning to code on your own, find a tool that works as-is, not one that needs debugging to work correctly.

Comment: It doesn't stop either way its not meant to. Just want it not to keep sending a new message each time. Also for the reply to Same which while I got so many and do I just remove the word or what do I do?

Answer (score 0):

In you linked code (that you should include in the question), you have:

```py
        while True:
            Run = True
            while Run:
```

First of all that is redundant. Secondly it said, "do this thing forever." Change that.

Just as an example of how this control flow *can* work and not be indefinite:

```py
i = 0
while i < 3:
    print("hi mom")
    i += 1
```

You see, this gives it a way to conditionally stop. You can also use `while True`, but you still need a mechanism to breakout.

```py
while True:
    if lunchtime():
        break
    keep_working()
```

Comment: When I tried that it didnt pop up once for the shared amount of times, so I cant check how many times its done it